# Failing to run Codeception tests with code coverage

Tags: php, code-coverage, codeception

I'm getting an error when I try to run tests using the --coverage flag.

---

### Input

```
php codecept.phar run acceptance testCest.php --coverage
```

### Output

```
[ErrorException] file_get_contents(http://project.local/c3/report/clear): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

### codeception.yml

```
coverage:
    remote: false
    enabled: true
    include:
        - application/*
```

### public_html/index.php

```
<?php require __DIR__.'/../c3.php'; ?>
```

### Versions

```
PHP: 5.5.12
Xdebug: 2.5.0
Codeception: 2.0.7
```

---

Thanks for any help!

J

Comment: is **project.local** set in your hosts file?

Comment: Where is your code that uses file_get_contents?

Comment: What is the URL can I go to in order to see the page?

Comment: @donald123 yeah it is set. The site works and I can acceptance tests no problem, it's just code coverage that won't work

Comment: @13375 The site is running locally at the moment using an Apache server

Comment: @jastew - did you ever resolve this issue? I am having the same problem now with a Laravel 4 setup.

Comment: @benslinger off the top of my head I think it was something to do with my virtual host so a URL in a config file was wrong.

Comment: I have same problem with Yii project - and only when running codecoverage - It would be nice if someone share a solution.

Comment: I have debugged once phpunit straight thru, until found that --coverage can be used simply by -c flag.. Somewhow -- was problem

Answer (score 1):

1. go to `phpunit.xml` and make sure you have something like this in the file:

   < logging >
           < log type="coverage-html" target="./CodeCoverage/"/>
   < /logging >
2. run this command:

   `$ phpunit --coverage-html ./report`
3. now check go to the directory and open the html file.

Comment: Are you sure this fixes what the question author asks for?